# How to pass the item ID to the ContentType.EditFormUrl inside our SharePoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, list-form

I have the following CSOM to change the "EditFormUrl" & "NewFormUrl" for a list's content type:-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             //customer sites
             string siteUrl = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/";
             string clientId = "***";
             string clientSecret = "***";
    
    
             using (ClientContext context = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
    
             {
                 try
                 {
    
                     context.Load(context.Site);
                     context.ExecuteQuery();
    
                     var omsWeb = context.Site.RootWeb;
                     context.Load(omsWeb);
                     context.ExecuteQuery();
                     //query for the alert period
                     List customerliveorderlist = omsWeb.GetList(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/userfeedbacksystem/");
                        
                     context.Load(customerliveorderlist.ContentTypes);
                     context.ExecuteQuery();
                     foreach (var ct in customerliveorderlist.ContentTypes)
                     {
    
                         ct.EditFormUrl = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/Lists/UserFeedbackSystem/EditForm.aspx";
                         ct.NewFormUrl = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/Lists/UserFeedbackSystem/NewForm.aspx";
                         ct.Update(false);
                         context.ExecuteQuery();
    
                     }
    
                        
    
    
    
                 }
```

currently the New form is working well, while the edit form is not working as I need to pass the ID of the item to the `ct.EditFormUrl` ? so can anyone advice on this?
Thanks

Comment: When you modify a a list item you are redirected to a form where `?ID=...` param is missing in the URL?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov so what i need to define inside `ct.EditFormUrl = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/Lists/UserFeedbackSystem/EditForm.aspx";`

Comment: My previous comment was a question

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov after i run my script and try to edit an item, i will be redirected to the url mentioned in the PnP which is `ct.EditFormUrl = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/Lists/UserFeedbackSystem/EditForm.aspx"`.. so i will get an error since the edit url is missing the ID

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov here is the full error `No item exists at https://**.sharepoint.com/Lists/UserFeedbackSystem/EditForm.aspx?List=ceb7e38a-ad40-468d-a474-edd00d6a16a2&ID=5721&Source=https://**.sharepoint.com/sites/TestGroupIntranet/Lists/UserFeedbackSystem/AllItems.aspx&ContentTypeId=0x010300F5238ABF33D8BC429DBBB013498555B1004AFAB19F0BA94242BE42542CDD31D64B&RootFolder=/sites/TestGroupIntranet/Lists/UserFeedbackSystem.  It may have been deleted or renamed by another user.`